# How to execute Appium parallel test on multiple Android devices which have same platform version/firmware?

Tags: android, selenium, appium

My current Appium parallel test is working fine on multiple Android devices which have different platform version/firmware. But when I execute the test on multiple Android devices which have same platform version/firmware, the test will throw many exceptions:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException

The test did create Appium driver instances with multiple Appium servers on different ports. But none of them are able to run any test cases.

**Tested on:** Appium v1.5.3 with real Android devices and Genymotion.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using `MobileCapabilityType.UDID`